# change select statement value using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some SQL below which is programmatically generated:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COMID, NAME, DATE)
SELECT DISTINCT 'COM001', 'John', '01-Jan-4501 00:00:00'
```

How can i amend this so that if it finds the date time of : `01-Jan-4501 00:00:00` then it replaces it with todays date?

Comment: Is the generated date always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to avoid some wrong or irrelevant values.

```
SELECT 
'COM001', 
'John', 
case 
when cast('01-Jan-4501 00:00:00' as date) > cast('01-Jan-2100 00:00:00' as date)
then cast(getdate() as varchar(30))
else '01-Jan-4501 00:00:00'
end
```

Another way is to create a trigger on that table that automatically makes the date field correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'COM001', 'John', 
case when date = '01-Jan-4501 00:00:00' then convert(date,getdate()) end
```